# Doubt about convergence of a sequence in $H^1(\mathbb{R}^3)$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functional-analysis, convergence-divergence, sobolev-spaces

Let's consider a sequence $\{f_n\}_n$ of $C^\infty_0(\mathbb{R}^3)$ complex-valued functions and suppose thet $f_n\to f$ strongly in $H^1(\mathbb{R}^3)$.
 What can I say about the convergence of the sequence $\{\vert f_n\vert\}_n$? Is it true that $\nabla\vert f_n\vert\to\nabla\vert f\vert$ in $L^2(\mathbb{R}^3)$?

Comment: See Theorem 7.6 in Gilbarg and Trudinger.

Comment: @John But I have complex-valued functions

Comment: do you really wanna know about $\nabla|f_n|$ and not about $|\nabla f_n |$?

Comment: @user159517 Yes

Comment: You can copy, as John suggested, Gilbarg and Trudinger's proof for Theorem 7.6:

Define
$$ u_\epsilon = \sqrt{f \bar{f} + \epsilon^2} -\epsilon $$
one computes 
$$ \int u_\epsilon D \varphi = - \int \varphi \frac{ f D\bar{f} + \bar{f} D f}{2 u_\epsilon + 2\epsilon} $$
This shows that $u_\epsilon$ is weakly differentiable with derivative in $L^2$, since $|f| / (u_\epsilon + \epsilon) \leq 1$ so is in $L^\infty$. Now take $\epsilon \to 0$.

Comment: @WillieWong Where do you use the smoothness of the sequence?